# How to Select - Update - Print with EF code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class "Notice" with an attr name "New". Now what I want is:

1. Select All Notice with `New == true`.
2. Update the `New` to false.
3. Print all what I get from (1) for the user (Razor).

So here is my code:

```
var Notices = core.Notices.Where(n => n.New == true).Take(20);

foreach (var n in Notices)
{
    n.New = false;
}

core.SaveChanges();

return View(Notices);
```

But after update all the Notices, I get nothing for my view!?!?

**Update:** here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ESN.Models.UserNotice>
<div>
@foreach (var n in Model)
{
    <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid";>
        @Html.Raw(n.NContent)
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to add your view code, as its impossible to tell what is going on without it. Also don't have variables with capital letters and the == true is unnecessary in your where clause.

Comment: Thank for your tips! Can you tell me why don't have variables with capital letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the deferred execution pitfall. You defined a linq query `core.Notices.Where(n => n.New).Take(20)`. That same query is re-executed in your view. But you just modified all notices to be not New. Possible solutions:

- `core.Notices.Where(n => n.New).Take(20).ToList()`
- Redefine the query after the modifications: `Notices = core.Notices.Where(n => !n.New).Take(20);`